# Python remove 'text' from lists made by xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I used xlrd to read through each cell of three columns to make three lists. Then, I appended the ith element of all three lists to a new list, making a new list of lists.

```
search_terms=[]
for row in range(0, book.nrows):
    search_terms.append([med_name[row], med_school[row], mentor[row]])
print(*search_terms[0:15], sep='\n')
[text:'Andrew Burkeland', 'Weill Cornell Medical College', 'Dave Cutler ']
[text:'Andrew Pence', 'University of Alabama at Birmingham School of Medicine', 'Jack Warran ']
```

Is there a way to take out the 'text:'? I am inputing each list in `search_terms` into `Entrez.egquery` to search for results on `pubmed`, and with 'text:' in the query line, I keep on getting 0 results.

Comment: @anonymous adding `str()` doesn't change anything because the contents are strings to begin with.

Comment: The problem seems to be your ```xlrd```search, which returns something like a ```Cell``` object. What you want are the *values*, so you need to use something like ```col_values()``` or ```row_values()```. Can you post the code that generates ```book.nrows```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume a simple table which is called 'students.xlsx'

```
Student     School     Mentor
John Doe    Harvard    Kornberg
Jane Done   Stanford   Pauling
```

and now open it with `xlrd`

```
import xlrd
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('students.xlsx')
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
row = xl_sheet.row(1)
```

Now let's look at the individual parts

```
print(row)
```

> `[text:'John Doe', text:'Harvard', text:'Kornberg']`

```
print(row[0])
```

> `text:'John Doe'`

```
print(row[0].value)
```

> `'John Doe'`

The problem is that `row[0]` is an [xlrd cell](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell) and not a string which is reason why it is necessary to get the content via `value`.

Now let's do it for all rows (except the header):

```
raw_data = list()
for row in range(1, xl_sheet.nrows):
    raw_data.append(xl_sheet.row(row))

author_list = list()
for raw in raw_data:
    author_list.append(list())
    for r in raw:
        author_list[-1].append(r.value)
print(author_list)
```

> ```
> > [['John Doe', 'Harvard', 'Kornberg'], ['Jane Done', 'Stanford',
> > 'Pauling']]
> ```

or short:

```
author_list = [[c.value for c in xl_sheet.row(n)] for n in range(1, xl_sheet.nrows)]
```